# jQuery Tablesorter From and To range not working - Cannot call method 'uiDatePicker'

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'uiDatepicker' of undefined.

HTML:

```
<input id="from" name="from" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
<input id="to" name="to" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
```

jQuery:

```
$("table") 
  .tablesorter({
  sortList: [[7,0]],
  theme : "bootstrap",
  widthFixed: true,
  headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}',
  widgets : [ "uitheme", "filter", "zebra" ],
  widgetOptions : {
    filter_reset : 'button.reset',
    filter_formatter : {

      7 : function($cell, indx){
        return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.uiDatepicker( $cell, indx, {
        textFrom: 'from',
        textTo: 'to',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear : true
      });
      }
    }
  }
}) 
.tablesorterPager({
  container: $("#pager")
});
```

**The reference of '7' before the uiDatePicker function is called references the 'date' column within the table.**

Scripts (loaded within the footer, jQuery loaded in header):

```
{{ HTML::script('assets/vendor/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::style('assets/vendor/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css') }}
```

Any advice / guidance as to why this isn't loading the uiDatepicker would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you check that you are using the most up-to-date version. If you are still seeing the problem, try the files within the working branch: https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/tree/working

Comment: I have used `bower update jquery.tablesorter` and it didn't update. Checking the version, I am on `2.16.1`. I believe this is the most up to date version? My dates are displayed in `1 May 2012` format, so I've changed this on the datePicker fields also, if that matters?

Comment: There are updates to the filterFormatter in the working branch.

Comment: Would they not have been included in the bower update I just did?

Comment: No, because the version number has not been updated yet.

Comment: Right ok, I will have to wait until it does then because I'm unsure of how to manually update. Thank you though @Mottie.

Comment: LOL, ok I'll update the repo. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Ok, now try the latest version.

Comment: Hi @Mottie, the same error is still appearing. I have updated my code also as I want to include pagination.

Comment: Can you please set up a demo; modify [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/e3V9V/) with a sample of your markup & code. Also, check to make sure that jQuery UI is loaded before the filterFormatter script.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e3V9V/35/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought your question was about using the `filterFormatter` which modifies the inputs within the table, but since your date inputs are outside of the table, you'll need to use code that looks something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/e3V9V/36/)):

```
var $table = $('#alerts'),
    validDate = function (d) {
        return d instanceof Date && isFinite(d);
    },
    updateFilters = function () {
        var range = [],
            from = $('#from').datepicker('getDate'),
            to = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');
        from = validDate(from) ? from.getTime() : '';
        to = validDate(to) ? to.getTime() : '';
        range[4] = from ? (to ? from + ' - ' + to : '>=' + from) :
            (to ? '<=' + to : '');
        $.tablesorter.setFilters($table, range, true);
    };

$table.tablesorter({
    sortList: [[4, 0]],
    theme: "bootstrap",
    widthFixed: true,
    headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
    widgets: ["uitheme", "filter", "zebra"],
    widgetOptions: {
        filter_reset: 'button.reset',
        // hide column filters
        filter_columnFilters: false
    }
})
.tablesorterPager({
    container: $("#pager")
});

$("#from").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'd MM yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        setTimeout(function(){ updateFilters(); }, 1);
    }
});
$("#to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        setTimeout(function(){ updateFilters(); }, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Mottie. Because I format the dates on both my table and the datepicker, will this cause any issues? The error has now gone, but any filter returns 0 results.

Comment: The dates will show in the input within the table as a number of seconds, so it shouldn't cause issues but it may confuse your users. Any filter where returns 0 results?